# Create a new dimension with a Desired Size than 1 in Numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I was Wondering while working with Numpy Array that if I have a 2d-Array of size (20,20) and I want to add a new Dimension of a certain size, How can I do it in Python.

Whenever I use np.expand_dims or np.newAxis it always will expand my existing array like this (20,20,1), I want it to be (20,20,10).

Please Guide me on this as I am new to NumPy and I couldn't find a solution to it anywhere with my keyword search on Google.

I am Transitioning from Java to Python. Informing about this so you guys can know what I am struggling with java in mind.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(6).reshape((2, 3))
print('2d Array')
print(a.shape)

# create 3d Array with size (2,3,5) and not (2 , 3 ,1)
```

Example input:

```
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5]])
```

Comment: Please include a minimal reproducible example of your code to make it easier to answer your question

Comment: What would the new values be? Copies of the initial? Zeros?

Comment: It can be a copy or non-even Identical. I am trying to figure out how to create a new dimension of my preferred size because the np.expandims or np.newAxis always create new dimension of size 1. @mozway

Comment: Can you add the expected output to your question for clarity? I hope my answer is what you need ;)

Comment: How do you do this in `java`?  Some for of loop that make 10 copies?

Comment: @hpaulj can you explain your question more precisely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [253]: a = np.arange(6).reshape(2,3)
In [254]: a
Out[254]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5]])
```

`newaxis`, as you note adds a dimension:

```
In [255]: a1 = a[...,None]
In [256]: a1.shape
Out[256]: (2, 3, 1)
```

Because of `broadcasting` that often is enough.  For example (2,3,1) can add to a (5,) to make a (2,3,5).  The (5,) was automatically expanded to (1,1,5).

```
In [257]: a2 = a1 + np.arange(5)
In [258]: a2.shape
Out[258]: (2, 3, 5)
```

`repeat` (or `tile`) can expand the dimension (any dimension):

```
In [261]: a1.repeat(5,2).shape
Out[261]: (2, 3, 5)
```

But the sum is the same as with `a1`.

```
In [262]: (a1.repeat(5,2)+np.arange(5)).shape
Out[262]: (2, 3, 5)
```

Comment: I wonder if OP wants  `a = np.arange(400).reshape((20,20)); b = a[...,None]+np.zeros(10)` …

Comment: Means a lot , Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `numpy.repeat`:

```
b = np.repeat(a[:, :, None], 5, axis=2)
```

Output:

```
>>> b.shape
(2, 3, 5)

>>> b
array([[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [2, 2, 2, 2, 2]],

       [[3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
        [4, 4, 4, 4, 4],
        [5, 5, 5, 5, 5]]])
```

Or `numpy.tile`:

```
b = np.tile(a[:, :, None], 5)
```

Output:

```
array([[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [2, 2, 2, 2, 2]],

       [[3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
        [4, 4, 4, 4, 4],
        [5, 5, 5, 5, 5]]])
```

Answer (score 0):

What is your desired output?

Maybe you mean that:

```
b = np.vstack(([[a] for i in range(5)]))
```

Output:

```
array([[[0, 1, 2],
        [3, 4, 5]],

       [[0, 1, 2],
        [3, 4, 5]],

       [[0, 1, 2],
        [3, 4, 5]],

       [[0, 1, 2],
        [3, 4, 5]],

       [[0, 1, 2],
        [3, 4, 5]]])
```

shape is : `(5,2,3)`
if that's not your meant and you want (2,3,5) and repeat any element 5 times you can use:

```
  b= np.tile(a[: ,: ,np.newaxis],5)
```